# Want to use a single database and single table (wp_posts and wp_postmeta) for two different sites

Tags: database

0

I am currently working on a project where I need to setup a theme and plugin which has same database and table for wordpress tables are: wp_posts wp_postmeta

I can edit these file as well as wordpress core files to achieve this task

Need: that new wp_common_posts and wp_common_postmeta table should look and work exactly like wp_posts and wp_postmet, repectively

I don't want to use any other additional theme(s) or plugin(s)